# Alternating row color in all tabularx

Tags: tabularx, rowcolor

I would like to colour every alternating row in every tabularx.

I know that I may gain this for all normal tabulars by using the following code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\let\endoldtabular\endtabular
\renewenvironment{tabular}{\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}\oldtabular}{\endoldtabular}
```

I know that for a single tabularx, I may use

```
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{tabularx}{...}
```

Now I dont know how to combine these for a code in the preamble, to achieve the same as in the first block of code, just for tabularx.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part you need to know to make this work is that the internal macro `\tabularx` expects an argument while `\tabular` doesn't.

Here is a possible way

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\let\oldtabularx\tabularx
\renewcommand*{\tabularx}{\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}\oldtabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}{lX}
foo & text text text text text text text \\
bar & text text text text text text text \\
baz & text text text text text text text \\
bla & text text text text text text text
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And now *forget about this*: a `tabularx` might be hidden in some package where you do not expect it. Instead, define a *new* environment

```
\newenvironment{ctabularx}[1]{% or whatever name you like
   \rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}%
   \tabularx{#1}%
  }{%
   \endtabularx
}
```